# loading saving and showing json results in javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

I have a php file called rows2.php that shows results like so after entering new fields in a database. It is simply showing the new id of the field :-

```
{'new_id':'92'}
```

I want to load this with javascript and add the new_id to existing list with : either side of the number and display it but I seem to be struggling? Many thanks.

The javascript to load the page and get the result is :

```
$.getJSON("rows2.php", function(result) {
  var new_id=console.log(result[0].new_id);
  document.getElementById('vehicle_list').value = '' + document.getElementById('vehicle_list').value + 'new_id' + ':';
})
```

Comment: And what is in the textbox?

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
document.getElementById('vehicle_list').innerHTML = ''+document.getElementById('vehicle_list').innerHTML+'new_id'+':';
```

instead of

```
document.getElementById('vehicle_list').value = ''+document.getElementById('vehicle_list').value+'new_id'+':';
```

`.value` is used only in case of input elements otherwise you must use `.innerHTML`

Answer (score 0):

Don't put the variable name (new_id) in quotes.

```
document.getElementById('vehicle_list').value = '' + document.getElementById('vehicle_list').value + new_id + ':';
```